# Listbox selection margin

Tags: wpf, listbox, selection

I have a WPF Tab Control.  Inside of it is a Listbox filled with some items. (There is only one item represented in the picture):

[image: unselected item]

The item has an orange gradient.

And here is the same item once I select it with the mouse:

[image: unselected item]

My area of interest is the little left side sliver of Blue coloring that I have circled in red.  I realize that this is the product of me selecting the item, and it shades the entire item blue to signify this.  However you will notice that this sliver of blue is not located in any of the edges except the left side.

My question is this:  How can I stretch the left side of my listbox item such that this blue sliver is gone, and the orange from the listbox item fills that area? I have played with margins and padding on everything I can think of, but to no avail.

Any hints, comments, and suggestions are much appreciated! :)

EDIT: As requested, the Xaml for the ItemTemplate.

The ItemTemplate uses a DataTemplate that is a static Resource.  The DataTemplate looks like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
        <UserControl MouseDoubleClick="MouseDoubleClick_Event">
            <DockPanel Background="<the orange gradient>" LastChildFill="True">
                <Image Name="AnImage" Height="20" Width="20" Source=" Binding Path=ImagePath}"/>
                <Label Width="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TheName}" />
                </Label>
            </DockPanel>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you show the pertinent XAML for this `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: I have edited it with the requested information! Thank you for taking an interest in my question!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this.  If I simply set a negative left margin on my ListBox, it moves the ListBoxItems over that amount and the sliver disappears.  Thanks to everyone for your interest!

Comment: No. You don't have these margins on the Windows XP/2003. But you can see them on the Windows 8.

Comment: I am not using windows 8.  This solved my problem, otherwise I wouldn't have stated it here. You really wanted to downvote a 6 month old post only to provide barely any insight?

Comment: @mherr, please consider that answers are for everyone, and other versions (and revisions) than the one you are currently using (or more precisely where using at 2011) must be considered. Settings a negative border sounds like a terrible idea to me, and you should be grateful for Manushin's broad perspective here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the problem is with your `TabControl` container, which you don't put, anyway, just set `Padding` to zero on the `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl Margin="0" Padding="0">
```

`TabControl`'s Default Style sets the `Padding` to 4 (that's the inner margin you are seeing) and binds the `Margin` on the content host to the `Padding` on the `TabControl`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! My mistake for not putting my tab control, but the tab control already had a padding of 0.  I tried a margin of 0 also, but it did not make a difference.

Comment: I have found the solution...and in retrospect it is quite simple.  I simply have set a negative left margin for the Listbox.  Thank you for your help :)